# Node.js exec event not firing inside Promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, exec, child-process

I have this simple code which is a promise as you can see:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

        var x = exec(`cd /maps && ls -la`, {}, function(err, stdout, stderr) {

            if (err || stderr) {

              reject(err + stderr);
            }

            resolve(stdout);
          });

          x.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
            console.log(data);
          });
    });
```

The `on` event is never fired while if i remove promise from around everything works

do you have any clue?

Comment: Try moving your `resolve` out of your callback function, and call it after `console.log(data)`.

Comment: How are you calling this promise returning function

Comment: @Darshan `some.do().then().catch();`

Comment: @RobertOliveira trying ... wil let you know in a while

Comment: @RobertOliveira nope, gets never resolved that way :(

Comment: @RobertOliveira you was right, i just confused stdout and stderr it works , if you so gentle to post that as answer i will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving your `resolve` out of your callback function, and call it after `console.log(data)`.

The reason may have been because you were resolving your promise too early.